# Libreoffice calc concatenate cell contents and parenthesis

Tags: concatenation, libreoffice, calc

Using Libreoffice Calc, here's what I'd like to do...

Where

`A1=XYZ`
`A2=123`
`A3=ABC`

I'd like to output into a single cell, this:

`123_ABC (XYZ)`

So here's what I did...

`=CONCATENATE(A2,"_",A3," (",A1,")")`

But calc doesn't like it at all.  I assume it has to do with the combination of " and ) characters.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the use of commas rather than semicolons.

Solution:

`=CONCATENATE(A2;"_";A3;" (";A1;")")`